# Confused about this line in priority queue

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, priority-queue

I was seeking a solution for the question of sorting characters by frequency. I got a few solution but couldn't make what one line did.

The full code of the program is:

```
class Solution {
    public String frequencySort(String s) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(char c: s.toCharArray()){
            map.put(c, map.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
        }
        PriorityQueue<Character> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>((a,b) -> map.get(b)-map.get(a));
        maxHeap.addAll(map.keySet());
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        while(!maxHeap.isEmpty()){
            char current = maxHeap.remove();
            for(int i =0; i<map.get(current); i++){
                result.append(current);
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

I have a problem with this code:

```
PriorityQueue<Character> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>((a,b) -> map.get(b)-map.get(a));
```

I don't understand what does this line mean at all. So you create a priority queue then why do we subtract map.get(a) from map.get(b). what is even a and b?

Comment: It's passing the constructor a lambda to act as a comparator.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Java 8 construct - a lambda expression.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_lambda_expressions

One of the `PriorityQueue` constructors takes a `Comparator` as an argument:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Comparator-

`Comparator` is a functional interface which means it declares a single abstract method. A functional interface can be implemented by defining a lambda expression. That's what happens in the code.

You can treat the lambda expression as the direct implementation of

```
int compare(T o1, T o2)
```

method of the `Comparator` interface.

Answer (score 1):

It's defining the "priority" of the queue to be whichever number (a or b) is bigger. The variable name gives you a hint as well - it's creating a max heap. After you've inputted all the data into the PriorityQueue, doing get(0) will return the largest number in the queue.

As the other answers have mentioned - the `(a,b) -> map.get(b)-map.get(a)` is a lambda function. Whenever a new element is inserted into the priority queue, that method will be called in order to determine where in the queue the new element should go.